# Javascript: Calling a function from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and I am building a page with those objecs
The objects have an image, image will be clickable and I want to count the clicks per image.
I am trying to assign the value for clicks from each object to "tclicks" and than hand "tclicks" over to the onclick function to count the clicks separately.
I am not sure if that works.

My current problem is that the value appears as NaN when the onclick function gets executed.
I am aware that I need to assign a starting value to clicks.
I tried it in various places.
In the object, in the function outside of the function. Either the value was not counting up, or I got an error as the element was set to 0
Where can I assign the starting value?

This is the array

```
var things = 
[
{img : "cat.jpg",
tclicks: "cleo_clicks",
id : "cleo"
},

{img : "shimi.png",
tclicks: "shimi_clicks",
id : "shimi" 
}
]
```

This is how I am building the page
    for ( var i= 0; i < things.length; i++){

```
var x = document.createElement("IMG");
x.setAttribute("src", things[i].img);
x.setAttribute(tclicks, things[i].clicks);
x.setAttribute("onclick", "countClicks(tclicks)");

document.body.appendChild(x);


}
```

And this is my onclick functions

```
function countClicks(clicks){

clicks ++;
console.log(clicks)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you can't assign clicks=0 where you define the array of objects like this:

```
var things = [
  {
    img: "cat.jpg",
    tclicks: "cleo_clicks",
    id: "cleo",
    clicks: 0
  },
  {
    img: "shimi.png",
    tclicks: "shimi_clicks",
    id: "shimi",
    clicks: 0 
  }
];
```

...but that's only half the problem.

In your click-increment function:

```
function countClicks(clicks) {
  clicks++;
  console.log(clicks);
}
```

...you will never affect a change on any object's click property because Javascript passes function parameters by value (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value).

You need to pass in the entire object to the function and allow it to modify the property value instead:

```
function countClicks(someObject) {
  someObject.clicks++;
  console.log(someObject.clicks);
}
```

...which means you need to change how the function is called, something like:

```
x.setAttribute("onclick", "countClicks(things[i])");
```

Note: above assumes things array is global, otherwise you'll need to further refactor.

Final note, calling JS pass-by-value is simplifying a little. You ca dive into the issue more here: [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Use an object and don't write it hard as onClick. It's too dangerous. You could override it. Use an eventListener instead.

```
function CountClicks(config){
    var img     = config.img;
    var tclicks = config.tclicks;
    var id      = config.id;
        var clicks  = 0;
    return{
        countUp: function(){
            clicks++;           
        },
        countDown: function(){
            clicks--;           
        },
        getCount: function(){
            return clicks;
        }
    }
}


x.counter = new CountClicks(things[i]);
x.addEventListener('click', function(){this.counter.countUp()});
```

Comment: I was trying to answer in a way that would require only incremental changes to the code, but this provides a nicer overall solution. However, in order to fully understand, you'll need to grasp closures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)